# queryString bug

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, query-string, tiles

I experienced a strange behavior for some queryStrings for my secondary tiles.
the string is the following:

```
 "/MainPage.xaml?link=" + "touch.facebook.com/home.php?refsrc=http://touch.facebook.com/home.php"
```

even if the second part is Uri.EscapeUriString()'ed or not, the app isn't starting through the secondary tile at all. it's instantly crashing, before loading anything.

is there anything I have to consider about queryStrings?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second `?` needs to be an `&`

**Edit:** URI's have a given form `page ? argument = value & argument = value & ...` etc

Parse your uri before you try using it:

```
string uri = "/MainPage.xaml?link=" + "touch.facebook.com/home.php?refsrc=http://touch.facebook.com/home.php";

string[] array = uri.Split('?');
if (array.Length > 2)
    uri = array[0] + "?" + string.Join("&", array.Skip(1).ToArray());
```

Comment: the uri is given by facebook, just copied, how should I catch such exceptions if this is really the issue?

Comment: See Edit.  Added some code to parse the uri before you try to use it. (If the double `?` is really your issue)

Comment: system.Net.httputility.UrlEncode & decode solved it, but i think the idea behind it is the same as yours. Thanks alot!